# Lightly Ionising Particles vs Weakly Interacting Massive Particles

Tags: particle-physics

I know the two to be candidates of dark matter, but in what respect(s) are they classified differently to one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightly Ionising Particles are not usually discussed as candidates for dark matter. It is a phenomenological description for the way some particles interact in a detector: They would ionize less than one would expect from particles with integer charge, i.e. electrons, muons, protons, etc. Typically one would expect a track from such particles, but with a lower ionization density than that from e.g. "mimimum ionizing particles" such as muons. As you can see this doesn't necessarily have to have anything to do with dark matter.

In contrast, weakly interacting massive particles describes a class of hypothetical particles to constitute the cosmological dark matter. Note that in recent years the original meaning of "weak" as in the "Weak Force" has been interpreted more freely. Anyway, weakly interacting massive particles would interact in your detector at most once, and thus not leave a track.

Many direct dark matter detectors are optimized and highly sensitive to very low-energy (keV) interactions. They can thus also search for any particle that is lightly ionizing, if such particles exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Lightly Ionising Particles vs Weakly Interacting Massive Particles

> T[he Cryogenic Dark Matter Search](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.081802) low ionization threshold experiment (CDMSlite) achieved efficient detection of very small recoil energies in its germanium target, resulting in sensitivity to *lightly ionizing particles* (LIPs) in a previously unexplored region of charge, mass, and velocity parameter space.

italics mine.

There is a confusion here, because the *lightly ionizing particles* refer to the detection of some particle entering the detector volume, not on an *exact particle hypothesis.*

The "Weakly Interacting Massive Particles" might also be lightly ionizing, depending on the hypothesis used in modeling the ionization seen in the detector.